# jquery variable not changing in url while using easyscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

The $catcount remains the same while passing, eventhough it chnages its value , the url sends the same old value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $catcount=1;
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function() {

            jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
                {   
                    'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                    'url': 'populates.php', 
                    'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content',
        'ajaxSettings': {'data':'cid='+$catcount},
        'onSuccess':function(){
                                    jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend('enable');
                                    $catcount++;
                                    alert($catcount);
                                  }     
                }
            );

        }
    );
   </script>
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you are incrementing the counter after you send the data via ajax.

Comment: yes , but the funtion triggers mulitiple time.and still it dosent change in the ajax url

Comment: Try adding it to the url instead of doing it that way. Added it as an answer, so you can see what i mean.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That was a great tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $catcount=1;
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function() {

            jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
                {   
                    'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                    'url': function() {
                             return 'populates.php?cid='+$catcount;
                     },
                    'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content',
                    'onSuccess':function(){
                                    jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend('enable');
                                    $catcount++;

                     }     
                });

        }
    );
   </script>
```